# Why doesn't some object work with NSDictionary shorthand?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, nsdictionary

In iOS 6 I can do this:

```
NSDictionary *d = @{anObject : "key"};
```

But apparently when the object is a UIImageView or UIWebView (or maybe others too), it crashes with:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIWebView copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent
```

Changing the dictionary declaration to the old way works:

```
NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:anObject,@"key", nil];
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: It's useful to read and understand the exception message.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The syntax is

```
NSDictionary *d = @{<key> : <value>, ...};
```

In your case:

```
NSDictionary *d = @{@"key" : anObject};
```

So your code tried to use `anObject` as the **key**. That failed for `UIWebView` because keys must
conform to the `NSCopying` protocol .

Comment: Thanks a lot. I always got them mixed up because of the old dictionaryWithObjectAndKeys.

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo: Yes, this is easy to mix up. But note that the Xcode autocompletion helps: If you type `@{` it is completed to `@{<key>: <object, ...>}`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the new syntax expects keys and values to be ordered in reverse, compared to `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys`:

```
NSDictionary *d = @{ @"key" : anObject};
```

Also, do not forget the `@` sign in front of `NSString` literal.

Answer (score 2):

Key first, value second.

```
NSDictionary *d = @{@"key" : nObject};
```